# Send Email Async

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asynchronous

This is what I've tried for sending email using the SendAsync() method. When passing the bool to send regular email it works fine. When sending with the SendAsync method no dice. Just looking for some tips if you see something wrong here. Thanks in advance.

```
private static void SendEmail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m, Boolean Async)
    {

    using (var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(EmailList.SMTP_GOOGLE, 587))
            {
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com","password");
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.Timeout = 3000000;


                if (Async)
                {
                    object userState = m;
                    smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(Smtp_OnComplete);
                    try
                    {
                        smtpClient.SendAsync(m, userState);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                            //Logging

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        smtpClient.Send(m);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                        //Logging

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just set up a simple console app to run the methods for testing

Because the email is being sent asynchronously, the console app will start the method to in a different thread and continue with its own execution. If it closes before the method to send the actual email completes, the email will fail to send because Visual Studio will kill that thread. Try adding the following line after your call to send the email to make the console app wait a few seconds:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

This should be more than long enough for the email method to send the email and finish before the console app closes and Visual Studio kills all processes. The code should work fine on a web server.

Comment: This was the issue so I gave jbdub the credit. I cannot believe I was overlooking something so simple thanks for your response.

Answer (score 11):

Your `using` statement is disposing the `SmtpClient` before the asynchronous send finishes.
That won't work.

Instead, you can either use C# 5 `await` to wait for the async send to finish inside the `using` statement, or get rid of `using` entirely for async sends and dispose the `SmtpClient` in the completion event.

Comment: No exceptions, No change by removing the using statement. I'll try await and see if that helps. Thanks SLaks for the reply.

Comment: @vikingben: Does the event get raised?

Comment: I can debug and step right down to the SendAsync method then it does not ever hit the smtp_oncomplete call back event.

Comment: Are you running this from an ASP.Net thread? They do funny things with SynchronizationContext that IIRC messes up `SendAsync`.

Comment: I just set up a simple console app to run the methods for testing. Everything checks out with the code I'm baffled to why it does not send.